# Convert uint32 address into char array

Tags: arrays, string, casting, char, uint32

I would like to convert a `uint32` to a `char` string for printing purposes. My `uint32` is an address that looks something like "`0x00402B00`"

I could care less about the preceding "`0x`", but it doesn't matter if it's in there.

How can I turn this number into a `char` string where:

```
string[0] = 0
string[1] = 0
string[2] = 4
string[3] = 0
string[4] = 2
```

....and so on.

Will something like this work?:

```
uint32 address = 0x00402b00;
char string[8];

sprintf(string, '%u', address);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

1. The `char` array needs to have room for a terminating NUL, so it should be at least 9 elements (not 8).
2. The `sprintf` format string argument needs to be a double-quoted string literal (not a single-quoted character literal).
3. A format string of `%08x` will ensure an 8-digit, leading-zero-padded, hex result (`%u` is an un-padded decimal).

The code should be:

```
uint32 address = 0x00402b00;
char string[9];
sprintf(string, "%08x", address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "x" conversion specifier from [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) (or sprintf) should do the trick.

You can omit the "0x" part if you don't want the 0x portion.

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    unsigned int address = 0xDEADBEEF;

    printf("Lowercase: 0x%x\n", address);
    printf("Uppercase: 0x%X\n", address);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`g++ -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread test.cpp && ./a.out`

```
Lowercase: 0xdeadbeef
Uppercase: 0xDEADBEEF
```